# Why are Eren and Mikasa shown not to be in the Walls in some flashbacks?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Why is it that in some flashbacks that it appears that Eren and Mikasa aren't in the walls? and no I'm not talking about the little loop things, on the outer parts of the walls, like where Eren lived.

[image: They don't appear to be in the wall in those flashback]

Comment: What is the "they" that you are referring to?

Comment: Some of the main characters, specifically, Eren and Mikasa.

Comment: Any supporting evidence how does it seem Eren and Mikasa are not in the walls? We know villages inside the walls are far away from each other. Major Citiies are just the protruding bits on the walls

Comment: The wall are very big and have a lot of woods so its in the wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The walls are massive, so it is most likely they are in the walls, just in a remote part

Comment: Thank you, my dude, but one question, in the flashback when Mikasa was kidnapped, and Eren lied that he was lost, the other guy said it was dangoures to get lost, because of wolves, and i dont believe they would have wolves in there.

Comment: @uselesscrapyoudontneedto do you really think so? If taking into account values of wall radius in first episode of anime, total area between wall Maria and wall Rose is about 270k sq. kilometers. I really doubt it is not enough for full-fledged ecosystem including wolves.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Standard character, plot, and location spoilers for Season 1 and 2 of Attack on Titan, and corresponding material from the manga. Some things we know about 
Mikasa's childhood home & the events that give us insight on its location:

- It is a decent-sized wood house located in a rural area, surrounded by trees, at the base of a hill, in a mountain-like region. On the side of the house, they store a hefty pile of wood,  and none of the surrounding trees looked to be cut down so we can assume that the area in question is likely in a forest or near a forest at the base of a mountain  (Manga, Vol. 2, pg 36)
- When Mikasa is kidnapped, she is taken to another rural location that shares the same wood-like housing structure, surrounded by trees, and with a mountain very close by in the back drop, and the house looks to be on an incline of some sort (Manga, Vol. 2, pg 42)
- Shortly thereafter we get a brief flashback to a childhood memory that confirms the house is at the base of forest, and the house is also a farmland house (Manga, Vol.2, pg 62).
- Now, we know that Eren lived at Shiganshina, and there are two forests on either side of this area, either being a plausible location for the location of Mikasa's childhood home. The area to the north east of Shiganshina is where the encounter with the Female titan takes place and so we know there's a forest there. The area to the north west of Shiganshina is where Krista's kidnapping occurs, so we know there's a forest there as well.
- But, as mentioned above, the childhood home of Mikasa was located near or within a forest, and the forest was also near a decent-sized mountain range. Cross-referencing with the terrain provided in Volume 2 of the manga, only mountain ranges within any of the walls are north west of Shiganshina. There are no mountain ranges to the north east of Shiganshina (Manga, Vol. 2, pg 38)
- Lastly, for the argument that Mikasa lived outside of the walls, remember that the location was close enough to Eren's home in Shiganshina that Eren and his father traveled to Mikasa's house by foot. And, in Attack on Titan, no one goes through titan territory without a horse. So, considering that they traveled to Mikasa's house by foot it would be safe to assume that the location they were traveling to was within Wall Maria but outside of Wall Rose.

That means that the most likely location for Mikasa's childhood home is somewhere near Chlorba, likely south east of it, but still within Wall Maria. At least until further information is released that proves otherwise.